# "Show" and "Shower"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, etymology

I'm a programmer and found myself naming an entity, which shows things, as `Shower`. Of course, the first time I read it, I remembered the freshness of the drops of water and nothing related to what it was supposed to mean. Then I [google-translated it into Russian](https://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#en/ru/shower) and found no nouns stemming from the verb `Show`.

So my questions are:

1. Is it correct to use `Shower` in the sense I meant?
2. If not, then what is the closest noun to the definition of a thing that shows something? I came up with `Presenter`, but it doesn't feel very close.
3. How did this word, which is evidently a derivative from a verb, evolve to mean an absolutely unrelated thing?

Comment: If you downvote please explain.

Comment: You have no exposure to MVP/MVC ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–presenter .

Comment: Do not Google-Translate things into Russian. (Do not Google-Translate anything at any time ever, for that matter, [except to have a laugh](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZV6.png).) Just look up the word in an actual [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shower#Noun_2): "*Shower*: 1. One who shows. 2. A man whose penis appears roughly full size both when flaccid and when erect." You want to call a function that, be our guest. As to the etymology, it can be [looked up in a dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shower) as well.

Comment: I suspect that one objection is that naming variables/entities/whatever is out of scope. You could name it Andrew with no loss of function (although the program would be less easy to maintain). Just limit the question to a problem of English. Here's [an extreme example](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word) but the edit didn't happen in time to save it.

Comment: @BlessedGeek It's not related.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The question clearly concerns English only. I just provided some context.

Comment: @RegDwigнt While the Wikipedia reference is funny, it neither provides a confident answer to my first answer, nor any answer to the remaining. So putting it on hold is quite a questionable act on your behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you're using it in code which will be seen principally by you and those after who maintain the code, there is no problem with "shower".

2) If it's going to be seen by the general public, then "viewer" is probably a better choice; in my experience, there is a connotation that a "presenter" is a person. Of course, a viewer can also be a person (especially used with television and other visual media), but it is far more often used for a physical or virtual device than "presenter".

3) "Shower" is not derived from the verb "show". "Show" derives from the Middle English word "*schawen*", or "*scheawen*", whose meanings relate to seeing; "Shower" derives from the the Middle English word "_shour", which relates to the North Wind, and the cold, rainy weather with which it is usually accompanied in the Northern Hemisphere. The apparent relationship between the two is a result of spelling simplification, giving them both the similar appearances, but different meanings.

Comment: Thank you, you've answered the third part of my question exhaustively. However I can't yet accept the answers to the first two. I was asking if it's correct to use the word "shower" in that sense without any specific context, because I've seen people use it, e.g., [in this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/171454/69999). So is it correct? Also, "viewer" has quite the opposite meaning from the perspective of "subject-object" relationship to the word I'm looking for, i.e., one shows (presents) to a viewer.